# Find the magnitude of a parallelogram?

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

Ok so far I know that first I am supposed to find angle ABC and angle ACB using the law of sines sinA/a=SinB/b=SinC/c . So that is what I did I got $sinABC/159 = sin71.5/15$. I got ABC is 71.5 yet I know I might not be right so how do I find ABC and ACB?

Comment: You have two parallel lines cut by a transversal. Some elementary plane geometry theorems about this configuration of lines will help you find the angles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ABC = 180 - CAB - ACB. You know CAB.

ACB = BCD - ACD.

ACD = ACB.

So **ACB** = BCD - ACB = 37 13'

BCD = BAD.

So, **ABC** = 180 - CAB - (BAD - CAB) = 180 - BAD = 108 31'